# How to get the value of this variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, clips

I am making an app with Clips as expert system. I was wondering if it is possible to collect the value of the ?result variable, or how to execute a piece of code and then get the result.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    clipsEnv = CreateEnvironment();
    if (clipsEnv == NULL) return;

    DATA_OBJECT theDO;
    EnvEval(clipsEnv,"(bind ?result (numberp (member$ 'Yes' (create$ 'Yes' ))))",&theDO);

}
```

What I put above is an example. My application uses a large .clp, I can not eliminate the variable because it is used to make other calculations.

For example I want to keep ?totalDays ?inputDays and ?variableResultado without modifying any code.

```
(bind ?totalDays (+ (* (nth$ 1 (GetDate)) 365)(* (nth$ 2 (GetDate)) (/ 365 12))(nth$ 3 (GetDate))))(bind ?inputDays (+ (* (- (Decimal (sub-string 7 10 ?FechaNacimiento)) 1900) 365)(* (Decimal (sub-string 4 5 ?FechaNacimiento)) (/ 365 12))(Decimal (sub-string 1 2 ?FechaNacimiento))))(bind ?variableResultado (* (/ (- ?totalDays ?inputDays) 365) 12))
```

Comment: How exactly are you using the variable ?result to make other computations? It's an important part of the solution to your problem.

Comment: The additional code fragments don't make your question any clearer. Are you trying to pass the result of one EnvEval to another? Where are these code fragments coming from? A CLIPS deffunction? A CLIPS defrule? A CLIPS batch file?

Comment: The code shown above is part of a huge XML file. That XML file is full of that type of code sentences. I need to execute those sentences and get the result of some variables. And answering to your question they are simple code sentences, I mean, no rules or functions. The point is that I've get multiple variables at one time, not just one variable.I really thank you your effort, though i think can do it adding global variables, and accessing them whenever is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. One possible solution is to define a global variable in a external file instead of a ordinary variable, and then get the result with  `EnvFindDefglobal()` and `EnvGetDefglobalValue()`.It's one of the possible ways I've found.

```
clipsEnv = CreateEnvironment();
EnvReset(clipsEnv);

if (clipsEnv == NULL){
     string = @"Error";
    return string;
}

filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"try" ofType: @"clp"];
cFilePath = (char *) [filePath UTF8String];
EnvLoad(clipsEnv,cFilePath);
DATA_OBJECT theDO;
EnvFindDefglobal(clipsEnv, "?*variable*");
EnvGetDefglobalValue(clipsEnv, "variable", &theDO);
string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ValueToString(GetValue(theDO))];
return string;
```

In the try.clp file:

`(bind ?result (numberp (member$ 'Yes' (create$ 'Yes' ))));
 (defglobal ?*variable* = ?result);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the return value of a function to a variable to retrieve it using EnvEval:

```
void *clipsEnv;
DATA_OBJECT theDO;
const char *theString;

clipsEnv = CreateEnvironment();

EnvEval(clipsEnv,"(numberp (member$ 'Yes' (create$ 'Yes' )))",&theDO);
theString = DOToString(theDO);
```